# counting number of occurrences per user in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using a google form to populate a google sheet similar to the template here which we use for tracking discipline at a public school

https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0Agoue3Pq0fSGdDJzX0pfb25xLXlQdFp4SnBVRjVDdVE&mode=public

Teachers fill out a form when students break a rule and the results are recorded in a form

I'm trying to rearrange the data into a report where the outputs would be listed on a new sheet by how many times a given student had violated a rule rather than each instance of a rule violation.

The input table looks a lot like the one linked, but for simplicites sake you can imagine

```
     A          B         C           D
Last name|First name|student ID#|rule violated
```

The rules are filled in by a form and the teacher selects from pre-determined rule violations

For the output I'm trying to use a query to get the data to look like this

```
Last name|First name|student ID#|cell phone|skateboard|swearing|kissing|
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this with a google sheets command such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [pivot](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#pivot) on rule violation type: that is, make different types into separate columns. Here is a query that does this:

```
=query(A:E, "select A, B, C, count(E) where C is not null group by A, B, C pivot D", 1)
```

The query selects A,B,C, grouping by these contents, and separate the entries in D into columns, filling it with counts of violations. I included column E just to have something to run `count()` on. The content of that column is irrelevant; it could be empty. (Google Sheets require counting by a column that isn't otherwise selected or pivoted on, so I could not use A,B,C, or D.)